# What is wrong in my regex /(?=^[a-z]+\d{2,})(?=\w{5,})/ pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex, positive-lookahead

This regex has to match passwords that are greater than 5 characters long, do not begin with numbers, and have two consecutive digits.

All the test cases are passing the regex test.

My regex is `/(?=^[a-z]+\d{2,})(?=\w{5,})/`

I have to use two positive lookaheads to solve this problem to pass the tests.

But astr1on11aut is not passing the test. Why?

Link to problem- https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/regular-expressions/positive-and-negative-lookahead

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/JnWV5J/1

Comment: It fails because "astr1on11aut" starts with letters (matching `^[a-z]+`) and then has a single digit which doesn't match your constraint `\d{2,}`. Therefore, the test for `(?=^[a-z]+\d{2,})` fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex fails because of the first lookahead pattern `(?=^[a-z]+\d{2,})`. The string "astr1on11aut" starts with lowercase letters:

```
astr1on11aut
^^^^
```

This matches `^[a-z]+`. However, the next part of the pattern demands two or more digits with `\d{2,}`, however the string only has one at that place:

```
   astr1on11aut
       ^^
       ||
digit -+|
        + --- not a digit
```

This causes the first lookahead pattern to fail.

You can express the validation rules more cleanly with three lookaheads:

- "greater than 5 characters long: `(?=.{5,})`
- "do not begin with numbers": `^(?!\d)`
- "and have two consecutive digits": `(?=.*\d{2})`

If we put them all together we get `/(?=.{5,})(?!^\d)(?=.*\d{2})/`

```js
const regex = /^(?=.{5,})(?!\d)(?=.*\d{2})/;

test("abc");
test("123");
test("123abc");

test("abc123");
test("astr1on11aut");

test("., ;_'@=-%");
test("., ;_'@123=-%");

function test(string) {
  console.log(`${string} : ${regex.test(string)}`);
}
```

Note that this regex doesn't require *letters*. Strictly following the requirements, the only thing explicitly asked for is digits. Since the type of any other input is not specified, it's left to be anything (using `.`). It's best not to make too many assumptions when writing a regular expression or you might block legitimate input.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not limited to using a *single* regex, I suggest splitting this into multiple tests in your host language (e.g. JavaScript):

```js
if (input.match(/^\D/)
    && input.match(/\d{2}/)
    && input.length >= 5) {
  // password policy fulfilled
}
```

Comment: Lookaheads are supported by all JS engines that I'm aware of. Look*behinds* are not supported in older ones.

Comment: Thanks. Let's keep the answer even simpler: not everything has to be solved as a single regex. Most of the times you have a host language, so let's leverage the power of that.

Comment: Amen to that. I feel like most of my time on the regex tag is spent trying to remind people that you don't *need* a regex for everything to do with strings. However, OP's task is specifically tied to making a regular expression here. I'd still endorse a solution that doesn't only use that because we should really be teaching people more how to use strings and rely on regex less. It's a useful tool but too often misused and misapplied by people who don't actually understand regular expressions yet decide to use them anyway. Email validations make me cry.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
(?=^\D.{5,}$).*(?=\d{2,})
```

The first lookahead asserts that the string must not begin with a digit but be at least 6 chars long; the second asserts that there must be at least 2 consecutive digits.

Answer (score 0):

This regexp passes all the tests

```
/(?=\w*\d\d)(?=\w{5,})(?=^[^0-9]\w*)/
```

I believe you could fix yours by splitting the first group.